# Edit page's tip windows bug

Tags: bug

There's a bug when editing a post where the "How to Edit" and "How to Format" windows get mixed in with the map links at the bottom of the page.

[image]

I'm using Chrome V58.0.3029.110.

Comment: Refresh, is it still happening?

Comment: @Mooz Yeah. It refreshes with no changes..

Comment: This was also reported on the [main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297223/323179) because it affects all sites. Furthermore, it's not just while editing; it affects the ask a question page too.

Comment: @Laurel Good to know